# Ant Design - How to fix table summary row at bottom with scrolling body (y-scroll)

Tags: javascript, antd

#### Link to CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-glade-15cce?file=/index.js

I'm using Ant Design Table component with x and y scrolls in order to have a fixed table height and a scrolling table body.
At the end of the table I have a Table.Summary.Row in which I would like to displays "totals".

#### Problem:

The summary row is inside the scroll and I would like it to be fixed (like the header) in order to always see the content of the summary row.

#### Tried alternative

I've tried to create a second form beneath the first one but when scrolling on the x axis in one form the other form does not follow.

Comment: Any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet a feature, there is a open feature request to add this functionality though. https://github.com/react-component/table/pull/503

Answer (score 0):

you can create common table summary (footer) component and wrap it with **<Table.Summary fixed>** like below code...if you add **<Table.Summary fixed>** inside your summary component then it won't work

```
const TableFooter = () => {
  return (
      <Table.Summary.Row>
        <Table.Summary.Cell index={0}>Summary</Table.Summary.Cell>
        <Table.Summary.Cell index={1}>
          This is a summary content
        </Table.Summary.Cell>
      </Table.Summary.Row>
  );
};

<Table
  summary={() => <Table.Summary fixed><TableFooter /></Table.Summary>}
/>
```